# Cannot upgrade iPad Air 2 from iOS 9 to iOS 13

Tags: itunes, ipad, upgrade, ios

I recently got hold of an iPad Air 2 that was sitting in a drawer. Had it recharged, seems to hold the charge. However it has iOS 9.3.1 and it says it cannot upgrade to 13 over the wire.

It requires iTunes and a computer. I also have a MacBook Pro (2014) running Mojave (10.14.6) so I fired up iTunes and connected the iPad via a USB cable.

The iTunes app sees the iPad and recommends upgrading to iOS 13. It asks me if I want backup. Nothing valuable on the iPad so I continue without backup. The iPad locks suddenly (no timeout). Then iTunes app (on Mac) asks me to type the unlock code on the iPad in order to continue. I do that and the iPad unlocks.

Then nothing happens. Neither on the Mac nor on the iPad.

**Will provide any other information as necessary. Let me know in the comments.**

What gives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why iTunes recommends iPadOS (iOS 13 equivalent for iPad), but it won't update as the iPad 2 is not compatible with iPad OS, and the highest software it can go to is iOS 9.3.5.

Here is a list of compatible devices on the [Apple website](https://www.apple.com/ipados/):

> - 12.9-inch iPad Pro.
>
>   - 11-inch iPad Pro.
>   - 10.5-inch iPad Pro.
>   - 9.7-inch iPad Pro.
>   - iPad (7th generation)
>   - iPad (6th generation)
>   - iPad (5th generation)
>   - iPad mini (5th generation)
>   - iPad mini 4
>   - iPad Air (3rd generation)
>   - iPad Air 2

You should be able to update to iOS 9.3.5 using the standard *Software Update* page (accessed by going to Settings -> General) over the internet without a computer.

The only thing you'll get from updating from iOS 9.3.1 is some security fixes, so leaving your device at that isn't a major issue.

## Solution for OP

The solution was to restart iTunes on the Mac.

Comment: Thank you! I'm sorry I wrote "iPad 2" instead of "iPad Air 2". My bad!

Comment: @AndreiRinea I’ll keep my answer for other users. Have you tried restarting the device?

Comment: I did not restart it but I restarted iTunes on the Mac and now it (the upgrade) has commenced!

Comment: @AndreiRinea Glad it worked